# Magento email success message after form submission returns blank page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magento

I used the **[a tutorial](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/)** to make a contact form module in Magento:

However, the way he describes how to output a success message doesn't work. Or I'm doing it wrong. I figured I could just:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success!');
```

But that just results in a blank page.

Does anyone know a way I could display a success message within the code outlined in the site above?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `customer/session` instead of `core/session`.
Also make sure to append a redirect to your code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess('Success!');
$this->_redirect('your-url/');
```